# Make search field in VBA Excel dynamicly focus results

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have a large Excel sheet and to that I have added a dynamic search field textbox and that works fine.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    ActiveSheet.Range("E6:E150").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="*" & [G1000] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

The problem is that if I filter out say row number 500 the result is not visible so I have to manually move the cursor up.

I tried this (and a lot of other stuff) without success.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("E6:E150").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="*" & [G1000] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Select
    End With
End Sub
```

It yield this

> "run-time error '424': Object required"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more info? I can't replicate this situation based on what you posted

Comment: Are you saying that if the `ActiveCell` gets hidden by the `AutoFilter` you want to move it to the first visible cell above it?

Comment: `AutoFilter` does not return a `Range` therefore you cannot `.Select` it. This is why you get an error *"object required"*. `.Select` needs a range object but `AutoFilter` does not provide one.

Comment: So your problem is that the cursor is in the wrong spot after a filter so you have to move it manually?  ie., `Application.Goto Range("E25"), False` Try it with `True` as well to see which one better suits your task.

Comment: This is an defining example of an [***XY Problem***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), more clear than most because the original problem `X` and the attempted solution, with secondary problem `Y`, are both documented within the same question.  Instead of trying to solve problem Y it would be better to focus on X.

Comment: Another part I don't get: if you filter rows `6:150` how can `AutoFilter` hide row **`500`**? Please provide more details on what you need to accomplish, and why

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the first visible cell above the currently selected but hidden activecell.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    with ActiveSheet
        .Range("E6:E150").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & [G1000] & "*"
        if activecell.EntireRow.hidden then
            dim i as long
            for i=activecell.row to 6 step-1
                if not .cells(i, activecell.column).EntireRow.hidden then
                    .cells(i, activecell.column).select
                    exit for
                end if
            next i
        end if
    end with
End Sub
```

I've changed the AutoFilter field to 1 as there aren't 4 fields in Range("E6:E150"); there is only 1. Also removed the unnecessary Operator:=xlFilterValues as that is only required when using an array as Criteria1.

Comment: _changed the AutoFilter field to 1 as there aren't 4 fields in Range("E6:E150")_ - good catch - that will be the next error he'll get (1004)

Comment: He doesn't seem too eager to provide details so +1 for the wild guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being unprecise.
Using select is no good idea I can see from implementing Jeepeds answer.
I found what I'm after:

`Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("E6:E150").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="" & [G1000] & ""
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
End With
End Sub`

Just that simple.